# Using OsaScript to send Imessage without having a buddy ID

Tags: imessage, osascript

Can someone show me how I would be able to send a message to someone who I have not messaged using message previously. When I use the code below I get the error: `execution error: Messages got an error: Can’t get buddy id "..."` if I haven't messaged them previously..

```
on run {targetBuddyPhone, targetMessage}
    tell application "Messages"
        set targetService to service "SMS"
        set targetBuddy to buddy targetBuddyPhone of targetService
        send targetMessage to targetBuddy
    end tell
end run
```

Thank you in advance